# Archivo .resources dañado. Se obtuvo una excepción EndOfStreamException

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación winforms que lleva años funcionando bien, al abrirla con Visual Studio 2005 para añadirle nueva funcionalidad y compilarla, me sale el error mencionado arriba
{"Archivo .resources dañado. Se obtuvo una excepción EndOfStreamException inesperada al intentar leer el encabezado ResourceReader."}
en la declaracion de un tipo de datos Splash.
Adjunto un pantallazo con la informacion detallada del error.
Si alguien puede indicarme como arreglar esto le estaria agradecido.
Un saludo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras probar unas cuantas cosas he encontrado la manera de arreglarlo.
En mi caso, al abrir el fichero Resource.resx empezaba a mostrar todos los recursos (imagenes) hasta que se ha quedado parpadeando en uno de ellos, al comprar dicha imagen he visto que pesaba 4 Megas, asi que he cerrado el Visual Studio, he copiado la imagen y la he hecho mas pequeña y con algo menos de resolucion, ahora la imagen ocupa unos 200Ks y al abrir nuevamente el Visual Studio 2005 me lo ha cargado bien.
Asi que en mi caso entiendo que el problema ha sido que el tamaño era tan grande que no cabia en la estructura de memoria habilitada para ello.
Espero que a alguien mas le pueda servir!